# Is it possible to migrate WiFi settings from one phone to another?

Tags: settings, wifi

My old phone knows about several (well, 13) WiFi networks over time (so, things like home, parents, friends, work, etc) - is it possible to migrate these known networks between two phones (or even to/from Windows 8/8.1)?

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot. App idea :) ?

Comment: Looks like 8.1 will bring this possibility in case of a backup.

Comment: @karancan Apps are sandboxed, and can't get to this data (otherwise, I might have taken this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded to a new phone all of my existing WiFi networks and passwords migrated to the new phone. I believe this was done through phone backup.

Under Settings -> Backup there is an option for "app list+settings".